# How to run .xproj file in vs2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, migration, .xproj

I have `.xproj` project and Visual Studio throws "**This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio**" exception. How can I run this project?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679083/how-to-open-xproj-file-in-vs2017-2015) , [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/)

Comment: I've tried these options, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As microsoft says you can not open with VS2019 16.3 and later

> Visual Studio 2019: In version 16.3 and later, you cannot load or
>   migrate xproj projects. For more information, see Migrating .NET Core
>   projects to the csproj format.

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2019

You have to one way migrate VS2017 or VS2019 16.2 or earlier

> When you open an .xproj file or a solution file that references .xproj files in Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2 and earlier, the One-way upgrade dialog appears. The dialog displays the projects to be migrated. If you open a solution file, all the projects specified in the solution file are listed. Review the list of projects to be migrated and select OK.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/migration/#visual-studio